# Is there a program to pair my phone with my computer for SMS messaging?

Tags: android, messaging, sms, smartphone

Sometimes I have to manage a conversations over SMS through my phone. This is especially frustrating when I'm trying to get work done on my computer.

I don't mind holding a conversation but there is a considerable amount of mental and physical task-switching by picking up the phone, turning it on, unlocking it, responding, deciding whether to keep holding it or set it down again and then repeat.

It would be very convenient if I could manage these conversations from my computer when I'm logged in.

Before anyone asks, I cannot ignore these messages and they often require a response. It is unreasonable to ask all of my contacts to instead contact me through an alternate preferred messaging app as SMS is already viewed as the lowest common denominator between platforms.

My phone is running Android. My workstation is Fedora running MATE Desktop.

Brownie points if there is a solution that integrates with Pidgin.

Answer (score 2):

[KDE Connect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) will do this if you're running KDE (but you're probably not with Fedora). There is a GNOME implementation too, [GSConnect](https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki), but I can't vouch for it (I run KDE). Those connect to your phone via an encrypted connection on the local network. No cloud service involved.

Though, honestly, the easiest is probably https://messages.android.com/ — though that will route your SMSs through Google, with all the privacy implications that has (which may not be any worse since you're already running Android).

Answer (score 0):

I use pushbullet, they have an API you can use if you don't want to use a gui. https://suitsandtech.co/pushbullet-for-linux/